# Testing in Rspec a random weather methods functionality depending on the random number generated

Tags: ruby, class, rspec

I am trying to have 2 tests to check the functionality of a method within the `Weather` class. The `random_weather` method should change `@status` depending on the result of `random_number`. However I cannot find a way to force `random_number` to be a certain number.

RSpec test:

```
require 'weather'

describe Weather do
  subject { Weather.new }

  it 'Can create an instance of Weather' do
    expect(subject).to be_instance_of Weather
  end

  it 'Can return sunny when randomly choosing weather' do
    subject.stub(:generate_random_number) {5}
    expect(subject.status).to eq "Sunny"
  end

  it 'Can return stormy when randomly choosing weather' do
    subject.stub(:generate_random_number) {9}
    expect(subject.status).to eq "Stormy"
  end
end
```

Weather Class:

```
class Weather
  attr_reader :status, :random_number

  def initialize
    @random_number = generate_random_number
    puts @random_number
    if (1..8).include?(@random_number)
      @status = "Sunny"
    else
      @status = "Stormy"
    end
  end

  def generate_random_number
    rand(1..10)
  end
end
```

example failure:

```
  1) Weather Can return stormy when randomly choosing weather
     Failure/Error: expect(subject.status).to eq "Stormy"

       expected: "Stormy"
            got: "Sunny"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/weather_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 options:

- wrap randomness in a method and stub this method
- wrap or a generator class that is injected, and inject a non-random generator in spec
- stub `rand`

I prefer the second option, but the first one may be enough.

### Private method

```
class Weather
  attr_reader :status, :random_number

  def random_weather
    @random_number = generate_random_number
    # ...
  end

  def generate_random_number
    rand(1..10)
  end
end

#specs
  it 'Can return sunny when randomly choosing weather' do
    subject.stub(:generate_random_number) {5}
    expect(subject.status).to eq "Sunny"
  end
```

### Generator injection

```
class Weather
  attr_reader :status, :random_number
  def initialize(random_number_generator: RandomNumberGenerator)
    @random_number_generator = random_number_generator
  end

  def random_weather
    @random_number = random_number_generator.call
    # ...
  end
end

class RandomNumberGenerator
  def self.call
    rand(1..10)
  end
end

#specs
  subject { described_class.new(generator) }
  let(:generator) { ->{ 5 } }    
  it 'Can return sunny when randomly choosing weather' do
    expect(subject.status).to eq "Sunny"
  end
```

### Stubbing `rand` in specs

```
  it 'Can return sunny when randomly choosing weather' do
    stub(:rand) {5}
    expect(subject.status).to eq "Sunny"
  end
```

Comment: Generator injection is by far the cleanest approach of the three.

Comment: Yeah, I like it the most. I'm aware that not everyone is very accustomed to this technique.

Comment: I did this however it seemed to still be random. As in my tests would sometimes pass and sometimes they would fail?

Comment: Why? You set it to a fixed value instead of a random - either by stubbing or by injecting a deterministic generator.

Comment: I am not sure, I implemented the private method option as this is the one I best understood, however it seems that the tests still pass and fail inconsistently as if the number is still random

Comment: It  means, that the method is not really stubbed.

Comment: I have edited the code with the issue that i am having

Comment: Try stubbing with `expect(subject).to receive(:generate_random_number) {5}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201102/discussion-between-bradley-plater-and-mrzasa).